# In-App audio with external display video

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm building an application where I need to play an audio file, such that the audio is played on the device speakers, while the video is played on an external display - which is connected either via the HDMI display adapter or Apple TV. Is is possible to specify where the audio plays?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the AudioSession audio routing by setting AudioSession.RoutingOverride.   The bad news is that this does not give much control beyond None and Speakers.

For more information see:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Category_Route_Overrides